# Is active Admin a good fit for a complex admin interface for a daily deal rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am building a daily deal app in Rails.

I just installed `activeadmin` gem which is really great and easy so that I can now create and monitor users. My need for creating and managing deals is quite complex:

I need to be able with the basic text fields (name of deal, date of deals, product name...) to add on the Deal's page stuff that for me (as a Rails newbie), i would associate more with a real CMS than with active admin, that is to say, i must add pictures (through url addresses on amazon S3), embed videos, associate features on certain deals such as vote up or down, and have a sort of html5 WYSIWYG html/text editor allowing me like i'd do on a wordpress site to move/add/arrange/re-position between each others texts, videos, sliders, call to action buttons, videos and much more.

I feel activeadmin is great for basic monitoring and maybe creation of objects for simple cases but as it works so much "automagically" I fear I won't have enough control or ability to bring many features and CMS stuff into active admin that i should build the "Deals admin Interface" on my own pages and not rely on active Admin for this.

What do you think about it ? Can I put all that stuff "inside" my Active Admin pages/controllers...or should I build it "outside" active admin ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ActiveAdmin isnt a good fit for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any answer for this question will be subjective..

formally, you can override anything (views, models, controllers) in activeadmin very easily. all this cases have minimal but enough instructions in [documentation](http://www.activeadmin.info/documentation.html)

there are some difficulties to override look&feel for example with [bootstrap](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1027) to receive more responsive layouts but in general case AA is administration framework designed for generic backends so this feature is not critical

according to your question to manage forms it supports `formtastic` so you can use any power of this gem

you can override form with generic `_form.html.erb` in one line with `form :partial => "form"`

you can use html-editors like [this](https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor) or [this](https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-wysihtml5) or other (like [this](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)) out of the box

BUT

this moment always insensibly comes when you begin to understand that some features can be done much better without any gem (not only activeadmin)

the real question is when will you cross this line but it is only up to you..

my advice: try to imagine most difficult issue and implement it with activeadmin. if you solve it with activeadmin - you can try to use it in future. if not => ...

one more thing: you can look at [rails-admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) - it is very promising and competitive to AA